# jquery get all values from table column

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to populate a select box with unique values from a table column using jQuery. So far my attempts have been futile but I am relatively new to front end development so I'm hoping someone can show me the light.

Cheers.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far, and what problems you've encountered. Also, include sample source code for the table.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This should get you started. Note that I use the cell contents for both the value and the text of the option. You may need to change this but it is unclear from the question.

```
var items=[], options=[];

//Iterate all td's in second column
$('#tableId tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').each( function(){
   //add item to array
   items.push( $(this).text() );       
});

//restrict array to unique items
var items = $.unique( items );

//iterate unique array and build array of select options
$.each( items, function(i, item){
    options.push('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
})

//finally empty the select and append the items from the array
$('#selectId').empty().append( options.join() );
```

Comment: missing an = in the items assignment

Comment: @redsquare
I came accross this in search for sort of the same thing. How would emplament a secondary array for the value?
options.push('<option value="' + link + '">' + item + '</option>');

Comment: @trobbins26 sorry, I do not understand what you mean - " secondary array for the value"

Comment: @redsquare 
Sorry... my ultimate goal is to pass table td:first-child to the option value, and pass table td:nth-child(2) to the options inner html text.

Comment: Thanks, This gives me an idea to the current problem that I'm facing.

Comment: $.unique is only applicable for dom nodes. not for strings or numbers. see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery's each function:

```
function FillSelect(){
    var vals = new Array();
    var i=0;
    var options='';
    $("#tbl tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(2)").each(function(){
       var t=$(this).html();
       if($.inArray(t, vals) < 0)
       {
           vals[i]=t;
           i++;
       }
    });

    for(var j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        options += '<option value="' + j + '">' + vals[j] + '</option>';
    }

    $("#sel2").html(options);
}
```

suppose 'tbl' is ID of your table, 'sel2'is id of select you want to populate. If you don't want to exclude first row then you can remove ***tr:gt(0)*** and put simple **tr** in selector expression.

Comment: use tbody as the header row should be a thead