# Return All Elements in a Table Column Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table where each row represents a company and each column represents a year.

Returning a collection of all the cells in a row will be easy. I could give the row an ID or class and look for all the `<td>` elements within that row. But how would I get all the elements that correspond to a particular year (column)?

I was thinking I could make up element IDs using the company and year values (e.g. item_1234_2011). This would make it possible, given an element's ID, to determine that elements corresponding company and year IDs. But how would I locate all the elements associated with a given year?

Comment: Does this linke help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237899/jquery-get-all-values-from-table-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing something like this `$('td[id$=_2011]');` comes to mind, if you use the format you specified.

Comment: Interesting. I'm reviewing all answers but this one is simple and is easy to use when all I have is the year.

Answer (score 2):

The first column would look something like:

```
$('tr > td:first-child', yourTable);
```

While associating with a year should look like:

```
var getCellsByYear = function (year, column) {
    column = column || 0; // Could set a reasonable default.
    return $('tr > td:nth-child("' + column + '"):content("' + year + '")');
};
```

**Edit** switching to `nth-child`, since that seems more appropriate.

Comment: **FYI** first-child should be replaced with `nth-child` if the years aren't in the first column.

Answer (score 2):

This simple example should get you going. Suppose you had the following markup, and you wanted the middle column of table cells.

**Markup**

```
<table id="stuff">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>i</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can select the cells (d, e, f) with the following jQuery:

```
$('td:eq(1)', $('#stuff tr')).each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3UgdA/

Answer (score 2):

`:nth-child()` pseudo selector could be handy. If you want to select the second column you can use `$('table tr>td:nth-child(2)')`

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sFVch/)

Comment: @Strelok: It may be "correct". It's still a bit awkward working from the year number.

Comment: @JonathanWood you can easily create a javascript array associating the year with the number of the column