# How can i get values of each column of a table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a drop-down(the value of drop-down is coming from local db) menu and i am trying to fetch the values of all the column using jQuery but the code which i am using isn't working.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.
Note:I am using clone method to dynamically add new rows in my table.

`jQuery`

```
function fnOnSubmit() {

  var formvalue = $( "#dataTable" ).serializeArray();
  jQuery.each(formvalue, function(i, formvalue){

      alert(formvalue.name+':'+formvalue.value);

  });
}
```

`HTML`

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="row">

      <td>
      <div class="id_100">
    <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <xsl:for-each select="faml/response/quicklinkresponsedto/searchby/datamapdto">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description"/>
            <option value="{datavalue}">
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            </option>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
     </div> </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
      <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  
        <div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
     <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button5" value="Initiate" class="buttons" name="Button5" type="button" onclick="return fnOnSubmit();"/></li>


  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery get all values from table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237899/jquery-get-all-values-from-table-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` function after getting the element based on selector:

```js
function fnOnSubmit() {
  $('#dataTable input:not([type=button]),#dataTable select').each(function () {
    console.log(this.name+':'+this.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="row">

      <td>
      <div class="id_100">
    <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <xsl:for-each select="faml/response/quicklinkresponsedto/searchby/datamapdto">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description"/>
            <option value="{datavalue}">
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            </option>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
     </div> </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
      <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  
        <div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
     <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button5" value="Initiate" class="buttons" name="Button5" type="button" onclick="return fnOnSubmit();"/></li>


  </ul>

</div>
```

---

Update 1:

```js
function fnOnSubmit() {
  var dropdownValue = $('#dataTable select').val();

  var flag = '';

  $('#dataTable input:not([type=button])').each(function () {
      // prefix the output with "#dropdownvalue" format:
      flag += '#' + dropdownValue + ...
  });

  // outside the loop, if you still want to end with the format, you can:
  flag += '#' + dropdownValue;
}
```

---

Update 2:

```js
function fnOnSubmit() {
  $('#dataTable input:not([type=button]),#dataTable select').each(function () {
      if (this.id === 'fldsearch') {
          var dropdownValue = this.value;

          // you can do something with dropdown value here...
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked.Thank you so much.Also if you can help every time I get values from my drop-down I want it to append it with '#' in the same loop.

Comment: @Saurav Sure. After getting value from dropdown, where do you want to append the value?

Comment: As soon as the function get the values from drop-down it should be append with '#'

Comment: @Saurav You mean: Getting the value from dropdown, then appending it to `<tbody>` tag with the id, and the id is refered from the selected `option` tag. Right?

Comment: I am so sorry ,i want it to prepend and not append . From the function you suggested i have appended '~' with each value coming from field and stored in a var flag and it looks something like this (flag =Guides~D1~i1~U1~Latest Offers~d2~I2~U2~). So I want to prepend the values of drop-down with '#'.

Comment: @Saurav So, the result should be like this `=Dropdownvalue#Guides~D1~i1~U1~Latest Offers~d2~I2~U2~`, right?

Comment: Yes something like this =#Dropdownvalue~D1~i1~U1~#Dropdownvalue~d2~I2~U2~#Dropdownvalue

Comment: mm.... I haven't understood the word `dynamic` yet. My code means: After clicking on the button, it will get the value from the dropdown first. Then starting a loop with another input values and prefixing the input values by the dropdown value. Or do you want to make an event which does the same thing when choosing another value from dropdown (not clicking on the button)?

Comment: I want it to work like in each () function(which you prescribed) whenever the function get the value of drop-down as (this.value) it should prepend it with # or since i am storing the values of my whole table in var flag such as (flag =Guides~D1~i1~U1~Latest Offers~d2~I2~U2~) so it should find values from drop down and replace it with #DropDownValues.

Comment: @Saurav Check with my update 2. If it doesn't what you mean, just comment to me. That's ok.

Comment: Yes its fine but its only taking the first row drop down value. If i have more than one row the second row drop down value is not coming in the if loop.

Comment: Is there any replace function in jQuery where the I can replace DropDown value with #DropDown value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204717/discussion-between-saurav-and-tan).